# How to get All Process which my app launch .Net Core

Tags: .net-core

I port a project to .Net Core The project have the following code:

`var searcherObj = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ParentProcessId=" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);`

I can't find ManagementObjectSearcher on .Net Core. Do you have other option to get all subprocesses;

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this is as follows -
Download the powershell https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases from there and source System.Management.Automation and related libraries to start a powershell command to get child process. The above release of powershell works with .NET core and thus will provide you a way to get child process without going through Management Object Searcher because that is not available in .NET core.